# Finding palindrome in C

Tags: c, palindrome

A palindrome is a word that reads the same from left to right and from right to left.
I wrote a program that finds palindromes from a console.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

#define SIZE 100

int main() {
    int i = 0, c;
    int left, right;
    char string[SIZE];

    while (EOF != (c = getchar()) || (c = getchar()) != '\n') {
        if (isspace(c) != 0) {
            if (i > 0) {
                left = 0;
                right = i - 1;
                while (right > left) {
                    if (string[left] != string[right]) {
                        i = 0;
                        break;
                    }
                    ++left;
                    --right;
                }
                if (left >= right) {
                    while (i > 0)
                        printf("%c", string[--i]);
                    printf("%c", c);
                }
                i = 0;
            }
            if (c == '\n')
                break;
        }
        else {
            string[i++] = c;
        }
    }
}
```

For example, we enter the words: dad sad mum. She outputs: dad mum. But if we write dad sad or dad mum sad. The output will be: dad mum.
That is, an extra space is printed when the last word we read is not a palindrome. How can you get around this situation?

Comment: `while (EOF != (c = getchar()) || (c = getchar()) != '\n')` gives me the creeps. Was this an exercise in short circuit evaluation? Not sure that does what you think.

Comment: Not to mention it calls `getchar()` ***Twice*** `while ((c = getchar()) && c != '\n' && c != EOF) { ... }` for a completely readable approach.

Comment: Read the whole string, then process it. Make your life simpler.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin That was the main reason why I mentioned it. as opposed to what we would expect, `while ((c = fgetc(stdin)) != EOF && c != '\n')` . The OPs condition logic is broken. Ex: a newline will succeed on the first expression, so the second will be skipped. EOF will *fail* on the first expression, goto the second, hit `getchar` again, still return EOF, and end up *succeeding* (because `EOF != '\n'` . This thing only works because of that injected `if (c == '\n') break;` buried near the bottom.

Comment: I liked the *creeps* description -- that was right on point...

Comment: @EugeneSh. I agree that approach is simpler but only for applications with small and non-streaming data. It's not clear whether the OP is in the situation though.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin luckily it only calls getchar twice when it gets to EOF, so it doesn't skip every other character. But then it will get into an infinite loop because `EOF != '\n'`

Comment: @Barmar Thus the need for the `if (c == '\n') break;` further down. The second half of the top while should just be thrown out.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin `while (EOF != (c = getchar()) || (c = getchar()) != '\n') {` only calls `getchar()` _once_ except when EOF occurs - and then it make little difference.  Code is amiss, but in other ways.

Comment: Aside - it is always better to initialize a buffer before starting to populate it.  Any portion that you do not populate of an uninitialized string can cause undefined behavior.  `char string[SIZE] = {0};` will do the trick for a string.

Comment: Anyway, the problem the OP is trying to fix, the tail space when the last word is *not* a palindrome, is because that whitespace char is actually printed after the while-loop that prints the previous palindrome word. That `printf("%c", c);` .Then, when the next word is processed and no palindrome is found, nothing is printed, the whitespace is already out there, the newline is encountered, and the outer loop breaks. That's the short of it.

Comment: I would do something [like this](https://godbolt.org/z/Yd1W3x859).

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica - ah - right you are. 1st test condition true, 2nd ever reached except when `EOF` then attempts read beyond `EOF`

Answer (score 1):

Code is convoluted

First read input properly and form a *string*.

```
for (i = 0; i < SIZE - 1; i++) [
  int ch = getchar();
  if (ch == EOF || ch == '\n') {
    break;
  }
  string[i++] = (char) ch;
}
string[i] = 0;
```

Then process the *string* in `string[]`.  Only print spaces when needed.

```
const char *separator = "";
int i = 0;
while (string[i]) {
  // Beginning of a word?
  if (!isspace(string[i])) {
    int start = i;
    int end = i;
    while (!isspace(string[end+1]) && string[end+1]) {
      end++;
    }
    // At this point, start indexes the 1st char of the word
    // and end indexes the last char of the word
    // Now find if a palindrome
    
    while (start <= end && string[start] == string[end]) {
      start++;
      end--;
    }

    // Found a palindrome?
    if (start > end) {
      fputs(separator, stdout);
      separator = " ";  // print a space _next_ time
      while (!isspace(string[i]) && string[i]) {
        fputc(string[i++], stdout);
      }
    } else {
      i = end + 1;
    }
  } else {
    i++;
  }
}
fputc('\n', stdout);
```

Answer (score 0):

Life is easier if you just read the string all at once, then process the string.

```
char s[1000];
fgets( s, sizeof(s), stdin );
char * p = strchr( s, '\n' );
if (p) *p = '\0';
```

If you wanted to read one character at a time you should read once, test twice:

```
int c;
while ( ((c = getchar()) != '\n') and (c != EOF) )
```

But trying to compute the palindrome-ness at the same time as reading seriously makes your algorithm *waaaaay* more complicated than it needs to be. Read a string first, then compute.

Now you can use integer indices from each end of the string. If you can get them to meet (or cross) then you’ve got a palindrome. Hint: put that in a function:

```
bool is_palindrome( const char * s )
{
  int left  = 0;
  int right = strlen(s) - 1;
  ...
}
```